# SQL - Updating rows in one table with values from another table - Multiple match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to append values in my `Customer` table with data from my `Sales` table.

The customer can have multiple records in the sales table:

Hereby a joined view:

```
SalesID CustomerID  SalesComment        CustomerComment
------------------------------------------------------------
1       14              Com1            Customer Comment 1
2       15              Com2            Customer Comment 2
3       14              Com3            Customer Comment 1
4       14                              Customer Comment 1
```

I want to make an update like this:

```
UPDATE Customer
SET Customer.ShopBookKommentar = CAST([ShopBookKommentar] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) +
                                 CAST(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + S.Comments AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
FROM Customer C 
INNER JOIN Sales S ON S.CustomerID = c.ID
```

But it's not updating any of the Customer rows where one of the Sales rows comment field is empty ('')

Comment: Oh, sorry about that

Comment: I just read your code more detailed ... You'd like to add all comments of a customer in the sales table to the field shopbookkommentar in the customers table - right?

Comment: The thing is: you can only update line per line and it is not possible to get the updated line result before your query has finished. In your case this means that just the last comment for one customer id in the sales table will be written to the customers table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  You need to use the table alias for the `update`:

```
UPDATE c
    SET ShopBookKommentar = c.ShopBookKommentar + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + S.Comments 
    FROM Costumer C INNER JOIN
         Sales S
         ON S.CostumerID = c.ID;
```

You only need the `cast()` if for some reason the intermediate result isn't big enough.  But that shouldn't be a problem.

EDIT:

I am guessing that you actually want to apply *multiple* comments from different rows of `Sales`.  That is a bit trickier:

```
UPDATE c
    SET ShopBookKommentar = c.ShopBookKommentar + c.somm
    FROM (SELECT c.*,
                 (SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + S.Comments 
                  FROM Sales s
                  WHERE S.CostumerID = c.ID AND
                        S.Comments IS NOT NULL
                  FOR XML PATH, TYPE
                 ).value(N'.[1]', N'varchar(max)') as scomm                   
          FROM c
         ) Costumer C INNER JOIN
         (Sales S
         ON ;
```

Comment: @PeterHansen . . . In that case, the `JOIN` is probably not finding any matching rows.  You should check the logic with a `SELECT`.

Comment: UPDATE Costumer
    SET ShopBookKommentar = Costumer.ShopBookKommentar + scomm
    FROM (SELECT c.*,
                 (SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + S.Comments 
                  FROM Sales s
                  WHERE S.CostumerID = c.ID AND
                        S.Comments IS NOT NULL AND
      s.Comments <> ''
                  FOR XML PATH, TYPE
                 ).value(N'.[1]', N'varchar(max)') as scomm                   
          FROM Costumer c
         ) Costumer  INNER JOIN
         Sales S ON Costumer.ID = S.CostumerID ;